# Smartyでassignを使わずに{foreach}のfromにキー(年)を指定したい

Tags: smarty

```
[2016] => Array
    (
        [0] => hoge
        [1] => fuga
    )

[2015] => Array
    (
        [0] => hoge
        [1] => fuga
    )
```

上記のような連想配列$rowsがあるとします。

これを{foreach}でキー(2016,2015)毎に実行したいのですが、
2016,2015は別々に表示させたい。

```
{foreach from=$rows[2016] item="row"}
  {$row}
{/foreach}

{foreach from=$rows[2015] item="row"}
  {$row}
{/foreach}
```

この2016(今年)と2015(去年)をうまく書くことはできないでしょうか。
↓は2015の方がうまくいかない。

```
{assign var="thisYear" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"}
{foreach from=$rows[$thisYear] item="row"}
  {$row}
{/foreach}

{foreach from=$rows[$thisYear-1] item="row"}
  {$row}
{/foreach}
```

年くらいassignなしでやりたい
↓は、まーエラーですよね。

```
{foreach from=$rows[$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"] item="row"}
  {$row}
{/foreach}
```

あまり綺麗とは言えないが、
foreach をネストし、ifを使えば出来る。

```
{foreach from=$rows key="year" item="row"}
  {if $year === $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"}
    {foreach from=$row item="value"}
      {$value}
    {/foreach}
  {/if}
{/foreach} 

{foreach from=$rows key="year" item="row"}
  {if $year === $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"-1}
    {foreach from=$row item="value"}
      {$value}
    {/foreach}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

もう少しスマートに書けないでしょうか。
初歩的なことかもしれませんがご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rows は 2016, 2015 で表示順になっているのですよね？
単純に foreach をネストするのはどうでしょうか。

```
{foreach from=$rows key="year" item="row"}
  {foreach from=$row item="value"}
    {$value|h}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: hm_ngr さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
すみません、問題の書き方が悪かったです。
確かに2016,2015の表示順で良いのならこれで問題ないのですが、
2016または2015の分だけ表示させたいという場合にどうしたら良いかと考えています。

Comment: if追加で出来ました。(綺麗じゃない気もしますが)

Comment: 記述を減らす場合、タイトルに反してしまいますが、表示用変数を $thisYear, $lastYear などとして assign を行い、制御をかける場合に{if !!$thisYear}を外側の foreach と置き換えるというほうが手っ取り早いかも・・・と自分は思ってしまいます。